# Ionic failed when build android SDK 27

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk

Honestly this is solved problem, but I just want to share the solution, just in case someone getting the same problem.

Getting failed building android, and it said.

```
> cordova build android --release
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
/home/her/code/com.xxxx/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I've browse a lot, the solution is to run ./sdkmanager.sh --licenses to accept all the license.

but, I still get the error. Short story, I double check the error and found that Ionic checking `/usr/lib/android-sdk/` rather than `/home/xxxx/android-sdk/`. 
So, I copied, the accepted licenses from `/home/xxxx/android-sdk/licenses` into `/usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses`.

Problem Solved.

Comment: next time you can use android studio to download sdk and accept licence , its more easy.

Comment: @Sam, already doing that, but more easy with CLI imo